# how to insert records from one table to another which is in different database dynamically

Tags: java

```
     Iterator iter1 = t.iterator();
     while(iter1.hasNext()){
    rowid1 = iter1.next();

    if (!t1.contains(rowid1)){
       System.out.println(rowid1);

   Statement st1=con.createStatement();

   st1.executeQuery("Select *  from table1 where rowid="+rowid1+""); //plz anybody corrct the query if it is logic then that too




       Statement st = con1.createStatement();

       st.executeUpdate("insert into table2 values("+rowid1+")";

    }
     }
  }
```

the last insert into prtion showing error messages so please help me correct the query. I want to  insert the entire row means suppose rowid is 21 with many colums which is not present in table2  so entire the colum value need to insert into the 21st row dynamically please help me.

Comment: what does ` System.out.println(rowid1);` prints and what error message you are getting?

Comment: Please mention your error here

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one parenthesis it seems...It should be...

```
st.executeUpdate("insert into table2 values("+rowid1+")");
```

Your question suggests that you want to copy records from one table to another table in a different schema. You can create two connection objects for each database.

```
Statement st1 = con1.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st1.executeQuery("select * from table1");
PreparedStatement ps = null;

while(rs.next())
        {
            ps = con2.prepareStatement("insert into table2 values(?,?)");
            ps.setInt(rs.getInt());
            ps.setString(rs.getString());
        }
```

/*I am assuming you have two columns in  your tables*/